# Storing encrypted datas in DB viewable by app in any time, but not by me (admin)

Tags: database, security, encryption

I need to store in my Database some datas that should only be read by the owner (specific user) or by my application (some background batchs).
But, those datas are highly sensitive, and I, the developper, don't even want to be able to retrieve it.
So :

- I can't just encrypt datas with a secret key kept in the server, because I would personally have access to it, so if I wanted, I could retrieve the entire datas.
- I can't encrypt with user password because my app need to have access to it without the user puting his password each time.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let the user *encrypt* something in such a way that only he can *decrypt* it, then you need a key to do this.

You could use the users password to do this, or you could use something else (a separate encryption key).

Now as for the password, you should not have access to that anyway; if you need the app to have access, then you should provide it with an access token of some sort, which will let the user get the access he needs without keeping the password in clear text. Entering the password should then only be necessary when the token is no longer valid (either due to timeout, manual cancellation / logout, or due to some kind of irregular event that might trigger a cancellation for security reasons).

Under a regime like this, where you don't need the password, your reason for not using the password as the encryption key falls away.

Note that no matter what you use as a key here, there will always be a question of trust here so long as you are doing the encryption on the server side; if you need your user to provide a key to encrypt / decrypt on your server, then what guarantees do they have that you will not simply steal that key and read their data anyway - or easier yet, simply not really encrypt it at all?

I realize that this solution *is* an improvement compared to using a single server-side secret key, since you will now have separate keys for each user, and keys that are not stored on the server (great in case someone is able to get unauthorized access to your DB), but an even better solution if possible, would be to let your users encrypt data on the client side. That way your server side logic would only ever see the encrypted data, and never even have to deal with either encryption logic or keys or any of that.